# Display Timestamp using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am trying to display timestamp using angular. At the backend on console log I am getting date like this 2020-09-03 00:00:00.0 but when I trying to get date at frontend it is displaying like this `1600021800000`. How can I display date in regular format?

This how I get date on console using spring boot -

[image]

And when get it at frontend it display like this -

[image]

How can I display date like this 2020-09-03 00:00:00.0?

Comment: is your dateTime on UI is a type of Long ?  new can display as new Date(dateTime) anyway

Comment: this date is automatically created at the time of registration of user at the backend i used private Timestamp dateTime;

Comment: @Dmitri Algazin i think i am getting time in seconds at frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your date is in $scope.dateTime

```
<p>{{dateTime | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss'}}</p>
```

Just put this wherever you want to show your formatted date in your HTML. Look up [angularjs date api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for more information regarding formatting

Comment: yeah 1600021800000 this is date in miliseconds. so i need to convert in date.